# Looping over two Data frames with different shapes

Tags: python, dataframe, logic, data-analysis, inventory-management

Hi I have two data frames namely sales and cost

```
**SALES**
Sku Product qty_sold
0    A       4     
0    A       3
0    A       1
1    B       6
1    B       2
2    C       1
2    C       1

**COST**

SKU Product qty_recieved Cost_price   Batch
0    A           6           24       ABC
0    A           10          23.47    XYZ
1    B           10          30       AC1
1    B           2           28       AC1
2    C           50          24       AC2
```

I want to implement First In First Out (FIFO) method, for example for SKU 0 first we received 6 qty so I want to run a loop in sales['qty_sold'], for first 6 items sold I want to add new column depicting the cost price of that specific batch and as soon the first 6 items are sold, the loop will continue but for second row in cost[qty_recieved'] table i.e for 10.

I have tried every method but due to different number of columns and rows in both data frames I always get an error or the loop is not iterated for required number of times.

sales [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Pr2U.png)
cost [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IozmQ.png)